# Is it really secure to call static class method from view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, view, partial-views

I am working on `Mvc 4 web application`. I have a static class which contains static `methods`. Suppose I have `Demo.UserHelper.GetUserName()` this method from class `UserHelper`.

**Is it really secure to call this method from view?**

### Edit

Basically from these methods I am retrieving some data from `DB`. The security is related to hacking. We are calling a `class method` from `view`. Is this really safe?

Comment: how do you expect SO to answer question about security if did not provide any details about the method itself nor what type of information passed/returned? (Assuming "really secure" really relates to security..., if not - please edit your question so it is clear what concerns you have).

Comment: Static class may not be suited here I guess

Comment: What do you mean by "Secure"? Be more specific.

Comment: As @SriramSakthivel mentioned what type of security are you asking about. If it is thread safety you are worried about, this depends on the implementation, so you have to share the code for your static method (but I assume it is safe). If you are worried about hacking, well this kind of code is done on server side and only resulting HTML gets to the user, so it doesn't really matter

Comment: @AKhudairy The security is related to hacking. We are calling a class method from view. Is this really safe?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov The security is related to hacking. We are calling a class method from view. Is this really safe? Actually I am trying to create an action which shows me notifications. In `_MenuPartial.cshtml`  I am creating a menu. On menu click it open dropdown and shows me notifications. For that purpose, to retrieve that notification I need to call method from view. Or is there any better way to do that?

Comment: There is no way to answer your question in current form - no one will be able to tell you if code is secure or not if all you provided is function name. There are plenty of guides on reviewing your code from security point of view around. Here is old [checklist for DB access review](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648227.aspx) - it may help you to clarify/scope down your question.

Answer (score 0):

Since as in your comment you say that your concern is hacking, that is the view is calling a class method which gets things from database.

Well, let me assure you that your fears are not valid. What happens is when a user makes a call your website, the MVC framework first thing figures out the route, so it knows which controller and method to call, then the action method prepares its model and viewbag, and calls a view (we are still on server side and your end user can't see anything) .. your view is a cshtml file which is basically html mixed with code (this is pretty normal) the MVC view engine renders your view as pure html and returns the result to the customer. So the customer only sees your html results and have no access to any of your code (unless you have javascript on the page, ofcourse the end user will be able to see it).

You might consider reading a bit more about http protocol in general, and then read about the MVC framework and how it works to help you better understand the round trips between client and server.

I hope this helps.

**Edit:**
Regarding the notification you need to pull. if it does get updated frequently, you might consider building it as API service, and having the page make a javascript call to get the latest notifications periodically (or maybe add refresh notification button to user)